# How can I add inner shadow to Raphael.js object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I found some drop shadows plugins based on blur or glow, also stroke opacity, but this is only simulation, and can't be used in case of inner shadow.

Also there is no simple filter in SVG specification, so you can't simply take advantage on it.

Comment: is this simply advertising your plugin? please rephrase the question and answer to match the site's format (e.g. elaborate on your attempts to solve the issue).

Comment: @EliranMalka What do you mean by advertising? then each answer with your own code is advertising your code? I would rather say that I wanted to share my solution with SO users, as they do with their solutions. That's why SO is so helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own plugin based on this two links:

https://github.com/dahoo/raphael.dropshadow.js

http://svgquickref.com/properties/filter/inner-shadow/index.html

HTML code (usage):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Raphael Test</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/raphael.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/raphael.innershadow.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="raphael"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var raphael, path, pattern;
                raphael = Raphael(document.getElementById('raphael'), 500, 500);
                path = raphael.circle(200, 200, 180);
                path.attr('fill', 'red');
                path.innerShadow(50, 0, 0, "green", 0.5);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Plugin code:

```
(function() {
    if(Raphael.vml) {
        Raphael.el.innerShadow = function (size, offsetX, offsetY, color, opacity, filter_id, input) {
            // not supporting VML yet
            return this; // maintain chainability
        }
    } else {
        var $ = function(el, attr) {
            if(attr) {
                for(var key in attr)
                if(attr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    el.setAttribute(key, attr[key]);
                }
            } else {
                return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", el);
            }
        };
        Raphael.el.innerShadow = function(size, offsetX, offsetY, color, opacity, filter_id, input) {

            opacity = opacity || 1;
            filter_id = filter_id || "innershadow";
            input = input || "SourceGraphic";

            if(size != "none") {
                var fltr = $("filter"),
                    offset = $("feOffset"), // offset
                    blur = $("feGaussianBlur"), // shadow bluer
                    composite1 = $("feComposite"), // invert drop shadow to create inner shadow
                    flood = $("feFlood"), // color & opacity
                    composite2 = $("feComposite"), // clip color inside shadow
                    composite3 = $("feComposite") // put shadow over original object

                fltr.id = filter_id;

                $(fltr, {
                        "height" : "150%",
                        "width" : "150%"
                });

                $(offset, {
                    dx: offsetX,
                    dy: offsetY
                });

                $(blur, {
                    stdDeviation: +size,
                    result: "offset-blur"
                });

                $(composite1, {
                    operator: "out",
                    "in": "SourceGraphic",
                    in2: "offset-blur",
                    result: "inverse"
                });

                $(flood, {
                    "flood-color": color,
                    "flood-opacity": opacity,
                    result: "color"
                });

                $(composite2, {
                    operator: "in",
                    "in": "color",
                    in2: "inverse",
                    result: "shadow"
                });

                $(composite3, {
                    operator: "over",
                    "in": "shadow",
                    in2: input
                });

                fltr.appendChild(offset);
                fltr.appendChild(blur);
                fltr.appendChild(composite1);
                fltr.appendChild(flood);
                fltr.appendChild(composite2);
                fltr.appendChild(composite3);

                this.paper.defs.appendChild(fltr);
                this._blur = fltr;

                $(this.node, {
                    "filter" : "url(#" + filter_id + ")"
                });

            } else {
                if(this._blur) {
                    this._blur.parentNode.removeChild(this._blur);
                    delete this._blur;
                }
                this.node.removeAttribute("filter");
            }
            return this;  // maintain chainability
        };
    }

    Raphael.st.innerShadow = function(size, offsetX, offsetY, color, opacity, filter_id, input) {
        return this.forEach(function(el) {
            el.innerShadow(size, offsetX, offsetY, color, opacity, filter_id, input);
        });
    };
})();
```

Comment: is this simply advertising your plugin? please rephrase the question and answer to match the site's format (e.g. the copyright header is redundant).

Comment: thank you, i was referring to the whole heading block (such content is superfluous as it has no contribution to the problem described).